# How to condense relative filenames in C++

Tags: c++, filenames, gnu

I'm building my own scripting language, just for fun (yes, I am aware of the difficulties of doing this), in C++ on Linux. This scripting language is going to have an import mechanism for including relative filenames in the interpreter pass stage.

So `/home/michael/foo/bar` might load `../bar/baz` which might load `../foo/baz` and so on.
The problem I get is I end up having to load filenames like this: `/home/michael/foo/../bar/../foo/baz` (relative filenames added to the current directory, recursively). This looks very silly in error output, and I imagine will cause other problems later, not to mention being quite inefficient.

How (apart from writing my own filename parser) can I 'optimise' or 'compress' the filenames so that I only have to load `/home/michael/foo/baz`?

I'm not averse to using a library, but I'd prefer to use POSIX/GNU C libraries/extensions or Boost if possible, although from a precursory look I can't find anything in either of those that does what I want, although maybe I just don't know what to search for.

Comment: Can you use POSIX functions? Try [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

Comment: @sftrabbit: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you! Post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX defines a function named [realpath](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath) that will resolve a path name for you. It sorts out `.`s, `..`s, extra slashes, and will also resolve symbolic links.

Comment: Be aware that .. cannot be safely resolved out (without examinjng the file system) in the presence of symlinks - /a/b/../c is not generally equivalent to /a/c if b is a symlink.

Answer (score 2):

Try [realpath](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/realpath/):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char resolved_path[100];
  realpath("/home/burgos/foo/../bar/../foo/baz", resolved_path);
  printf("\n%s\n",resolved_path);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sftrabbit got there first, so I'm accepting his answer. Thank you though!